# getRectSubPix and borderInterpolate in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

The documentation for OpenCVs [getRectSubPix](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=getrectsubpix#void%20getRectSubPix(InputArray%20image,%20Size%20patchSize,%20Point2f%20center,%20OutputArray%20patch,%20int%20patchType))() function:

```
C++: void getRectSubPix(InputArray image, Size patchSize, 
Point2f center, OutputArray patch, int patchType=-1 )
```

contains the statement:

> While the center of the rectangle must be inside the image, 
>   parts of the rectangle may be outside. In this case, 
>   the replication border mode (see borderInterpolate() ) 
>   is used to extrapolate the pixel values outside of the image.

But I can't see a way to set the borderInterpolate mode in getRectSubPix.  Many other OpenCV functions ([boxFilter](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=copymakeborder#boxfilter), [copyMakeBorder](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=copymakeborder#copymakeborder), ...)  allow you to pass in the borderInterpolate enum, but not getRectSubPix.

Is this just a documentation error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement "***replication border*** mode (see [borderInterpolate()](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html) ) is used to extrapolate the pixel values", clearly states that it uses a predefined mode known as `BORDER_REPLICATE` to estimate the pixels outside the image boundary, You cannot use other Border methods like `BORDER_REFLECT`, `BORDER_WRAP`, `BORDER_CONSTANT`, etc.